# Table design for a simple event driven architecture - order workflow

Tags: database-design

I am looking for an idea for the DB / Table design for an async application communicating via message queues.

There is a food delivery application. In order for me to say the order is ***complete***, the following services should accept it. (It is async..)

1. restaurant service
2. driver service

If one of them rejects, the order is ***cancelled*** immediately.

I have an order_details table (just to keep things simple).

```
order_details
 order_id
 status
```

Should I keep the status of restaurant and driver acceptance in this order_details as a separate column or should they be stored in separate tables?

My concern is - what if we need to add another component in the workflow in future. for ex: payment service .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a combination of both solutions you are thinking about.

In the table(s) describing each task, I would have a `status` field for this task. And a trigger on that field. Once the status for the task is decided, the trigger will send the value to the main table. The main table would have a copy of that status field (yes, it goes against normalization, but toward convenience), and a final status field as computed field from all individual statuses:

```
create table order_details (
 order_id primary key, 
 status null compute (case when status_restaurant="complete" and status_delivery="complete"
                                 then "complete"
                           when status_restaurant="cancel" or status_delivery="cancel"
                                 then "cancel"
                           else null
                     end),
 status_restaurant null,
 status_delivery null
)

create table restaurant (
 order_id references order_detail(order_id), 
 status null
)

create trigger restaurant_status
after update
on restaurant 
begin
  update order_detail set status_restaurant=NEW.status
  where order_detail.order_id=NEW.order_id
end
```

Now, every time you change the status of the restaurant task, it would be reflected in the `restaurant` and in `order_detail`.

Yes, there is a chance that someone change the status of a task directly in the `order_table`. If you want to avoid it, you can write a stored procedure which gather statuses from individual tasks and decide the final status. Just do not forget to call this stored procedure. And that would have to be from a client, since triggers often have problems with SP execution. Some DBMS has `events` which can rectify that, but...

As alternative, you can get rid of the final status in the database completely, and calculate it on the fly, each time client wants it. It can be done as a VIEW or just a code on a client side.